# Временная таблица (материализация) с WITH

Tags: sql, postgresql

Создаёт ли `with` временную таблицу? Если да, то создаёт ли вложенный `select` временную таблицу?

Насколько я вижу из [доки](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/queries-with), да. Но вопрос тогда, в чём существенная разница между `with` и `select`? Я думал, что это `alias`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос зависит от вашего ответа на вопрос
«А какой версии у вас
*PostgreSQL*?» :-) . Ваша
ссылка — про древнючий **9.5**. Начиная
с версии **12**, материализация общих табличных выражений происходит
«[по-умному](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html)»:

> However, if a `WITH` query is non-recursive and side-effect-free
> (that is, it is a `SELECT` containing no volatile functions) then it
> can be folded into the parent query, allowing joint optimization of the two
> query levels.  By default, this happens if the parent query references the
> `WITH` query just once, but not if it references the
> `WITH` query more than once.  **You can override that decision by
> specifying `MATERIALIZED` to force separate calculation of the
> `WITH` query, or by specifying `NOT MATERIALIZED` to force
> it to be merged into the parent query.**  The latter choice risks duplicate
> computation of the WITH query, but it can still give a net savings if each usage
> of the WITH query needs only a small part of the WITH query's full output.

(Выделение добавлено.) Так что они более-менее равны
подзапросу, по крайней мере во многих случаях.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем [так](https://pgcookbook.ru/article/common_table_expressions_cte.html#:%7E:text=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC,%2D%20INSERT%2C%20UPDATE%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20DELETE.&text=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9.)

> Табличные выражения можно назвать анаголом временных таблиц,
> актуальных только в рамках одного запроса. В табличных выражениях
> может быть как SELECT, так и модификация данных - INSERT, UPDATE или
> DELETE. ... Каждое табличное выражение имеет имя и может определять
> имена возвращаемых полей.

Разница в том что вы подготавливаете выражение для дальнейшего использования в основном запросе. Временные таблицы можно использовать в нескольких запросах в рамках транзакции. А табличное выражение только в рамках одного запроса.